# Eclipse errors -"Failed to load JavaHL Library" and "Widget disposed too early!" and "XPCOM error"

Tags: eclipse, svn

I have been updating my code in Eclipse using SVN and my workpsace crashed at some moment. I am using SVNKit instead of default SVN in Eclipse.

I got the error:

`**Failed to load JavaHL Library.**`

, but I have exited the Eclipse. So next time I started eclipse , I couldn't because of that error - which I have seen in *.medatada/.log*

My next error is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Widget disposed too early!
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference$1.widgetDisposed(WorkbenchPartReference.java:172)
```

and

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: XPCOM error -2147467262
at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.error(Mozilla.java:2414)
```

Which is showing every time I started eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here is the answer for my own question.

For the error:

```
**Failed to load JavaHL Library.**
```

The way I fixed it is that I have deleted my **.snap** file in my workspace :

> /workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/

I have deleted that file and that error "!MESSAGE Failed to load JavaHL Library." was not reporting anymore.

For the next error, which was saying:

```
XPCOM error -2147467262
```

I have located eclipse.ini file and I have located "-vmargs" and I have added below:

> -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/usr/lib/xulrunner

Then I have run eclipse, and it all WORKED.
I have removed the specified line afterwards, when I successfully entered the worspace

In reference to the second problem , the link for more information is located here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21409186

I hope this will help someone :)
And I hope it will help someone not to create new worspace and import all data all over again, like I did at first :)